# Capping Token Sale

Tags: crowdsale

How does one have a capped crowdsale?
This is my code so far

```
contract CrowdsaleToken is StandardToken{

 string public constant name = "TestCoin";
 string public constant symbol = "TCC";
 uint public constant decimals = 6;
 address public constant multisig = 0x0;

 uint public constant PRICE = 500;

 uint public maximumEther = 1;
    uint public totalEther;

    function () payable {
        // Do not accept payment if recaudation is above maximumEther
        if (totalEther >= maximumEther) throw;

        // Emit tokens
        totalEther = totalEther + msg.value;

        createTokens(msg.sender);
    }

  /*function () payable {
     createTokens(msg.sender);
 }
 */

 function createTokens(address recipient) payable {
     if (msg.value == 0) {
         throw;
     }

     uint tokens = msg.value.mul(getPrice());
     totalSupply = totalSupply.add(tokens);

     balances[recipient] = balances[recipient].add(tokens);

     if (!multisig.send(msg.value)) {
         throw;
     }
 }

     function getPrice() constant returns (uint result) {
         return PRICE;
     }

 }
```

I actually haven't tested it yet, and am going to soon. Just wanted to get feedback to see if any modifications should be made.

Comment: If you are creating public crowdsale I'd suggest to use some of the contracts from OpenZeppelin. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale.